# designing large doc lib application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

What are the major issues we should consider while designing very large size document library even large list. I understand threshold factors, but what steps to follow while doing design? it should facilitate both query & search.

Pl guide with steps...

Comment: Are you using enterprise, or foundation? Only one of the two makes sense. And this has nothing to do with SharePoint Designer, which is the tool provided for power users to do some customizations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all more information. Large as in file size or file quantity? Other information like do you require unique permissions on files? Do you need to import the documents? and very very important what version of SharePoint?

Once you have this basic information you can make some decisions:

1. Maximum file size
2. Maximum file size to be crawled
3. View size, views and audiences - especially for unique permissions as these are MUCH slower
4. Import documents - what tool are you using
5. Crawl method - 2013 has a benefit here as it has continuous crawl
6. Plan plan plan perform a full audit and a health check on your current system, are you ready for this? http://en.share-gate.com/blog/top-10-reasons-sharepoint-2013-migration-failed
7. Managed metadata - Planning this for tagging and searching of documents will significantly increase usability of your new document library, once in use it doesn't matter about the size
8. Architecture, do you need to span multiple blob stores? (2013 would be much better again because of shredded storage)

If this has more points for you to raise then please feel free to edit your question and respond with a notification that you have done so, then I can elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

There are many areas to consider when designing the storage of large amounts of content, but, just like with everything else in SharePoint, there is no one-size-fits-all solution. There are different ways to approach large content data size and a large number of smaller documents (not necessarily a large amount of data, but a large number of files).

There are a large number of software boundaries and limits of SharePoint outlined in [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx) depending on the version you're working with. All of the points under "Content databases" and "Lists and libraries" should be considered, but the key points here are:

Content Databases (read the article for descriptions of when each applies):

- Content database size (general usage scenarios) -> 200 GB per content database
- Content database size (all usage scenarios) -> 4 TB per content database
- Content database size (document archive scenario) -> No explicit content database limit

Lists and libraries:

- Documents -> 30,000,000 per library
- Items -> 30,000,000 per list

But these are the MAXIMUM thresholds before performance degradation is likely, though even that depends upon the farm's resources.

You may also want to look at ways to safeguard your farm's performance and usability from degradations occurring due to your large list.

Check out [Manage lists and libraries with many items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010173667.aspx) and Joel Oleson's article [Managing Lists and Libraries with Thousands or Millions of Items](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=241).

Read about this. And then read some more. You can't be over-prepared.